# How to open an org presentation?

Tags: org-mode

I have a presentation I [wrote using presentation mode](https://github.com/kirkins/puppet-pop-machine/blob/master/presentation.org) a few years ago. Now I'm trying to open it and I forget how to do it.

I'm trying to run emacs command `presentation-mode` but nothing is found. I tried installing `presentation-mode` but there was no package with that name on Melpa. I also tried installing `org-present` but the command still doesn't work.

Is presentation mode built in to emacs or do I need to install it? Also how do I open it?

Comment: What you are linking to is a plain org file. Presentations are usually done by exporting to the presentation format (PDF if you are using beamer,  HTML if you are using org-reveal or similar), but maybe [this page](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/non-beamer-presentations.html) will ring a bell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the mode I was using for presentations at that time. I believe it was `outline-presentation-mode` which is a minor-mode for `org-mode`. It doesn't seem to be very popular, as I didn't see it in Melpa. However after loading the elip file manually I seem to be loading my presentation in emacs as I remember it:

[image]

Links:

https://p4bl0.net/shebang/emacs-outline-presentation-mode.html

https://web.archive.org/web/20160623023613/http://pablo.rauzy.name/files/sen-meeting_2013-01-17.outline

Elisp file:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160810000826/http://clandest.in/emacs.d/plain/outline-presentation.el